# Manually setting url.intended and wrong browser history

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

Based on a eloquent created event I set `url.intended` in the session to a special page.

```
$this->request->session()->put('url.intended', '/my-special-page');
```

So when a user creates a row on a specific table (via a form), and is not logged in, it redirects them to login (after middleware) and upon successful login, redirects them to `/my-special-page`.

All of this is working, but when I create the row, login, get redirected to `/my-special-page` and hit back, I'm presented with the page users would see if they login normally.

Why is this happening and how can, if the user hits back, got back to the page they were previously on?

What is happening:

```
form submit -> login -> special-page -> user hits back -> normal page for logged in users
```

What should be happening:

```
form submit -> login -> special-page -> user hits back -> form page
```

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to edit the 'browser history' is by using [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by editing `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Just edit the redirect line so it becomes `return redirect('/my-special-page');`